# I see Error 2601 in profiler when I ALTER PROCEDURE, but no error or message is shown in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am running `SQL Server 2005 SP4`. I have a stored procedure that I want to update, so I run the `ALTER PROCEDURE` in SSMS and it succeeds. I then run the procedure and it works fine. (It is a 1090 line set of unit tests.)

I happened to have Profiler running and it shows 11 rows of the Exception event class with text data of

> "Error: 208, Severity: 16, State: 0" followed by almost 200 rows of
>   the Exception event class with text data of "Error: 2601, Severity:
>   14, State: 1".

I cleared Profiler and ran the same `ALTER` statement again and had the exact same result. My server is very tight on memory, so the 208 is not a big surprise, but I don't understand what the 2601 is trying to tell me. Note: The errors occur as a direct result of the `ALTER`, not as a result of executing the procedure.

Can anyone enlighten me as to the meaning of the 2601 error in this context?

Comment: I did find this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/6a18d713-f22e-4baa-8477-de4c7dfc05bd, but it doesn't provide any useful information.